# Why is header transition working in chrome and firefox, but not in edge?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, css-transitions

Im currently building [this](http://23-rulez.tk) project for some pals. However, the transition that I use to move the whole page to the left, when the menubutton is clicked. This animation does work in chrome and Firefox but not in edge. Why is this?

header HTML:

```
<div id="page" class="">
    <div class="wow fadeIn" data-wow-duration="1s">
        <header class="fixed topheader">
            <div class="leftheader toplist">
                <a id="logo" href="#">23-RuleZ</a>
            </div>
            <nav id="navbar" >
                <ul class="menulist nav">
                    <li class="menuitem topitem"><a href="#Join" class="toplist">Join 23-RuleZ</a></li>
                    <li class="menuitem topitem"><a href="#blog" class="toplist">Blog</a></li>
                    <li class="menuitem topitem"><a href="clanwar/" class="toplist">Clanwar</a></li>
                    <li class="menubutton topitem"><a  id="sidemenu" class="topbutton" href="javascript:void(0)">  &#9776; </a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>
```

Some JS:

```
  var a = document.getElementById("sidemenu");
  a.onclick = function() {
        if ($('#page').hasClass('moved')){
            $('header').removeClass('moved');
        }
        else {
            $('header').addClass('moved');
        }
        $('#page').toggleClass('moved');
        $('.sidebar').toggleClass('visible');
        $('#sidemenu').toggleClass('error redbottom');
    return false;
  }
}
```

CSS:

```
.bodyheader {
    background-color: #efefef;
    height: 60px;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #CCC;
        transition: all 0.5s ease;
      -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;    /* FF3.7+ */
      -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;      /* Opera 10.5 */
      -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease; /* Saf3.2+, Chrome */

}

.topheader {
    height: 80px;
    color: #FFF;
    font-weight:700;
    font-size:20px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #666;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
      -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;    /* FF3.7+ */
      -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;      /* Opera 10.5 */
      -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease; /* Saf3.2+, Chrome */

}
```

All code is available at the site.

Any help is appreciated!

**EDIT:** What would be superb, is that the width changing of the page of the page is animatable. I could get this to work previously.

Answer (score 0):

Edge is quite a new browser so it may take a while for all HTML/CSS/JS to be supported, blame the browser.

Comment: transitions are working, just not at the header. For example, the sidebar is moving animated to the left.